# How to define the type of an unknown variable with MaxScript

Tags: maxscript

I have the following code.

In this code, the testListnerA function gets the socket variable and uses it in the testListerB function.

```
global socket = ??

fn testListnerA =
(
   tcpListener = DotNetObject "System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener" dotNetIPAddress port
   tcpListener.Start()s

   msgReceived = ""

   socket = tcpListener.AcceptSocket()

   while true do
   (
      sendByteStream = DotNetObject "System.Byte[]" 10000
      socket.Receive sendByteStream
      encoding = DotnetClass "System.Text.UTF8Encoding"
      msgReceived = trimright (encoding.UTF8.GetString(sendByteStream))
   )
)

fn testListnerB =
(
   socket.Close()
)
```

In order to use variables outside of functions, I decided to make the socket variable a global variable.
However, unlike Integer, Float and String, I don't know how to define unusual types like tcpListener.AcceptSocket().

How should I use the socket variable in such a case?

Answer (score 0):

Completely define the socket outside of the functions. Then call that socket variable as a parameter of each function.

```
(  
    fn testListnerA sckt =(
      msgReceived = ""
      while true do
      (
         sendByteStream = DotNetObject "System.Byte[]" 10000
         sckt.Receive sendByteStream
         encoding = DotnetClass "System.Text.UTF8Encoding"
         msgReceived = trimright (encoding.UTF8.GetString(sendByteStream))
      )
      return msgReceived
    )

    fn testListnerB sckt =(
        sckt.Close()
    )

    -- Create the socket object and store it in a variable
    tcpListener = DotNetObject "System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener" dotNetIPAddress port
    tcpListener.Start()
    socket = tcpListener.AcceptSocket()
    
    -- call the functions with the 'socket' variable from above as input param:
    testListnerA socket
    testListnerB socket
)
```